# Unique ID Column Returns Multiple Values

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, spark-koalas

I have a Koalas data frame that has what I would expect to be a unique ID column ("index") created by resetting the index on a dataframe using `breakdf2 = breakdf.reset_index()`

I believe I can prove that breakdf2 only has one record for index = 0 using
`len(breakdf2.loc[breakdf2['index'] == 0])` which returns "1".

However, when I run

```
for i in range (10):
  print(breakdf2.loc[breakdf2['index'] == 0][['index', 'Primary_dp_margin', 'Sell_dp_margin']])
```

I get

[image]

How is it that I'm getting 2 pairs of values for a seemingly unique identifier "index"?

Comment: What does `breakdf2[breakdf2['index'].duplicated(keep=False)]` return?

Comment: After you `reset_index`, what does `breakdf2.loc[breakdf2['index']==0]` return?

Comment: Chris, I had to modify your code to be ```breakdf2[ks.DataFrame(breakdf2['index']).duplicated(keep=False)]```, but got a blank result  from there

Comment: Speshal, I already reset the index of breakdf to create breakdf2. I take your question to mean what happens if I just run ```breakdf2.loc[breakdf2['index']==0]``` on the newly created breakdf2 dataframe. It returns many columns that I omitted from my question, but index is 0, Primary_dp_margin is -0.297432, and Sell_dp_margin is NaN (yet another result...)